# How do I Open Labels/Buttons with C# code?

Tags: c#, arrays, path, location, label

Take a look on the code ,i hope you will understand what I'm trying to do:

```
private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string[] Folders = Directory.GetDirectories(txtFolder.Text);
        string foldername;
        int count=0;
        foreach (string f in Folders)
        {
            foldername = Path.GetDirectoryName(f);
            Label newlabe = new Label();
            newlabe.Location = new Point(12, 58);
            newlabe.Text = foldername;
            count++;
        }
}
```

as you can see i insert a Directory Path into text box ,  then I opened an array which contains the sub Directories,the next step is to open labels which contains the sub directories names from the directory i insert to the text box, that's not working , what should i do ?

Comment: you're not adding the label to your form.  And you're using the same point for each label location, so once you do add them to the form, they'll be stacked on top of eachother

Comment: consider posting the folder names to a listbox. you wont have to worry about location

Answer (score 1):

Use some kind of container and stack/add the labels into it. You don't need to assign a location to the label, as the container (depending on the container layout algorithm) will layout them for you.

I dont know whether you use WinForms or WPF or something else, so I will not write any sample code.
But here is some pseudocode:

```
create a container and add it to the form
for each folder
    create a label for the folder
    add the label to the container
```

by the way, have you tried a TreeView control?

Comment: im using WinForms , im not familiar with the TreeView control ... if you can write a code thats will be great!